# A Server Behind A Router

Tags: python, apache, networking, router

I'm trying to set up a server behind a router, and I've been able to reduce it to the following problem:

I use:

1. Siemens SL2-141 Router.
2. Windows 7 64-bits with Python 2.7.

I run:

- server.py:

  ```
  import socket
  sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  sock.bind((IP, 8080))
  sock.listen(1)
  sock.accept()
  print 'success'
  sock.close()
  ```
- client.py:

  ```
  import socket
  sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  sock.connect((IP, 8080))
  sock.close()
  ```

---

1. When IP = '127.0.0.1' **it works**.
2. I set up a static IP:

   ```
   > Network And Sharing Center > Change Adaper Settings > Local Area Connection
   > Properties > Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) > Properties
   > Use The Following IP Address:

       IP Address:      10.0.0.200
       Subnet Mask:     255.0.0.0
       Default Gateway: 10.0.0.138

   > Use The Following DNS Server Addresses:

       Preferred DNS Server: 10.0.0.138
       Alternate DNS Server: - - - -
   ```

   And when IP = '10.0.0.200' **it works**.
3. I set up port forwarding on my router:

   ```
   > http://10.0.0.138/
   > Username: Admin
   > Password: Admin
   > Advanced > Virtual Server > Port Forwarding > Add:

       User Defined: Test

       From Internal Host IP Address:       ALL
       Forward to Internal Host IP Address: 10.0.0.200

       Protocol:                            TCP
       External Packet Port Start:          8080
       External Packet Port End:            8080
       Forward To Internal Host Port Start: 8080
       Forward To Internal Host Port End:   8080

   > Apply (and reboot router, just in case).
   ```

   To my understanding, if I leave the server IP '10.0.0.200' and set the client IP to my public IP it should work, but **it doesn't work** ("no connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it").

I tried doing the same thing with an Apache server and the result was similar: browsing localhost worked, browsing the static IP worked, but browsing the public IP didn't work (port 80 gave me the router setup page, and port 8080 just couldn't connect).

Final notes:

- I turned off my firewall.
- I checked that the port is open (http://www.canyouseeme.org/) and it is.
- I checked that the server is listening (netstat -na | find /i "8080") and it does.

Any ideas what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To my understanding, if I leave the server IP '10.0.0.200' and set the client IP to my public IP it should work, but it doesn't work.

That's right, if the client is on an external network. On the local network if you use your public address it may or may not work depending on if your router implements NAT reflection (if not it will drop the packets). You should use the your local (private) IP address on your local network. Many routers allow you to configure DNS records for local resources (that override records from the DNS server, implementing a type of "Split DNS"). That way you can use one DNS name to get the correct address.

If you're problem is with a connection from a client on the external network, it sounds like somehow your NAT router is not port forwarding. I don't have your model of router, but I see this line:

> From Internal Host IP Address:       ALL

And wonder if you have to allow `From External`.

Also are you sure this rule is enabled? (I only ask because the last time I had a problem like this I had created the forwarding rule correctly but it wasn't enabled.)

If you're still stuck, try removing the rule and re-test if the port looks open to http://www.canyouseeme.org/. I would also re-test when NOT running your server program (to test if the external port scan is misleading, which can happen).

Finally, when you write:

> I turned off my firewall.

Do you mean Windows Firewall? You'll want to double check that too because Windows Firewall can allow local connections while blocking remote connections.

Comment: It turns out the router didn't route me through the internet, so the public IP wasn't identified with my machine. I tried running the client (and browsing the Apache server) via Tor, and everything worked.

Thanks.